# Vaadin RichTextArea height autosize

Tags: vaadin, styling, richtextarea

I use vaadin 8. I need some help about RichTextArea.

1. To make RichTextArea height dynamically changeable. When text
   achieves max height it creates vertical scroll but i don't want that
   scroll. I need to increase its height dynamically.
2. How to wrap text in RichTextArea. I stil can't find the way.

Comment: what do you mean with wrap text? like, pressing enter? or putting in a line break programmatically? Or does it not go to a new line when you reach the end of the last line?

Comment: Removed unwanted words

Comment: Cashbee, when i reach the end of line it doesn't wrap text

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any elegant way to make this component increase its height to avoid vertical scroll bar.

And your second point is quite strange : word-wrap is the default behavior in richtextarea component. You can check it on official demo : https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/text-input/rich-text-area

Regards

Sebastien